# apt-get upgrade goes to an infinite loop while downloading stuff

Tags: 12.04, apt

My Ubuntu 12.04 installation (yes I don't want to upgrade just yet) is giving me trouble updating. This has been happening for more than a week. I run `apt-get update` no problems but when I run `apt-get upgrade` it keeps on re-downloading the same many times and I can't get any updates anymore e.g.

How can I fix this?

```
azg@olympus:~/code/rm/debug$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libsvn1 openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-7-dbg
  openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-source subversion
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 320 MB/329 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,309 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]
Get:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:4 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:5 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:6 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:7 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:8 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:9 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]             
Get:10 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:11 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:12 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:13 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:14 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:15 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:16 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:17 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:18 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:19 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
Get:20 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.1 [16.5 MB]            
5% [20 openjdk-7-jdk 16.4 MB/16.5 MB 99%]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oracle-java7-installer
```

Then add this repo to you software sources

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && apt-get update
```

Then reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```